# Google Visualization API working locally, but not on external server?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, google-visualization

I'm building a dynamic pie chart to show election results using the Google Visualization API and jQuery, and I had it (sort of) working on my local machine, and wanted to get some feedback, so uploaded it to an external server, now everything I try to load gives me a "No Data" error.

I've got two files, one which gets data from a database and converts it to JSON, and one which displays the visualization, depending on what areas are checked. You can see it here:

http://www2.lichfielddc.gov.uk/sandbox/pie.php?electionid=14

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I may be on to something.

I downloaded it and tested it locally and as you said it works fine. However, in the datasource i was using (data.php) if I put a delay (sleep(1)) it stopped working. I think it was because you were drawing the chart out of the ajax success callback.

Try this:

```
    function drawVisualization() {          
    $('.poll').click(function() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Party');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Votes');

        var polls = [];

        $('.poll:checked').each(function(){
            polls.push(this.value);
        });

        polls.join(",");

        url = "http://www2.lichfielddc.gov.uk/sandbox/piedata.php?pollid=" + polls;

        $.getJSON(url, function(d) {

            data.addRows(d.length);

            var items = [];
            var num = 0;

            $.each(d, function(i, o) {

                console.log(o);

                data.setValue(num, 0, o['party']);
                data.setValue(num, 1, o['votes']);

                num++;

            });

            new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Stepping through the code: By the time you call the draw() method, the object 'data' has no data in it. This is likely because the modifications to the data object are not in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tribal that it's a timing issue, because the live version does work sometimes. There's a couple of other lurking bugs, that aren't behind the presenting issue, but ...

```
polls.join(",");
url = "http://www2.lichfielddc.gov.uk/sandbox/piedata.php?pollid=" + polls;
```

`polls.join()` returns a string, it doesn't do the join in-situ. And `url` isn't being declared as a local variable